# How do you verify a certificate chains to a specific CA?

Tags: .net, x509certificate, certificate, pki, x509certificate2

I currently have an application that needs to verify that a certificate is trusted by a specific CA.  The issue I have is that the issues certificate may actually belong to a root CA that is cross certified with the CA I would like to verify against... so I want to make sure that I properly build a chain to the cross certified root ca.  An example of what a chain of trust may look like is below.

```
1) Root CA1 -> Inter CA1 -> John Doe Signed Cert
2) Bridge CA Root -> X-Cert Root CA1 -> Inter CA1 -> John Doe Signed Cert
```

Both of the above certificate chains are valid, but I want to ensure I have chain number 2 built.

```
X509Certificate2 johnDoeCert = GetJohnDoeCert();
var chain = new X509Chain();
chain.Build(johnDoeCert);
chain.ChainElements[chain.ChainElements.Count - 1];     // I want to ensure this is Bridge CA Root
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is check the information against something that you know about the target certificate, in this case Bridge CA Root

You can either check against the Issuer Name on the certificate like this:

```
string bridgeCAIssuerName = "CN=Bridge Root CA, OU=PKI..."; //Fill in with correct information
if(ch.ChainElements[ch.ChainElements.Count - 1].Certificate.IssueName.Name == bridgeCAIssuerName)
{
  //This happens if it was true
}
```

You can use the same technique to check the thumbprint or serial of the certificate.